# How to check index of object in NSMutableArray if objects are same?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, enumeration

I have an NSMutableArray of NSNumbers.
I enumerate over array, and for each "1" in there I need to check its position in array and do some stuff. This is how I do it:

```
for (NSNumber *number in fieldArray) {

    int temp = [number intValue];
    if (temp != 0)
    {
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            switch ([fieldArray indexOfObject:number]) {
                case 0:
                {
                    CCSprite *x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"x.png"];
                    x.position = ccp(53,265);
                    [self addChild:x];
                }   
                    break;
                case 1:
                { 
                 //this code never gets called
                }
```

As I have a "1" at position zero of the array my switch statement never going to go anywhere but number 1. How do I fix that? How to check the position of the stuff in array cell?

Why I need this and why I do it this way. I'm making a tic-tac-toe game. I store field in NSMutableArray with capacity of 9. So each number in array is a cell on play field. If the cell is empty, the array holds zero for that position, if there is x - there is 1 value in array, and if there is zero in cell - the array holds 2.
When drawing time comes I iterate over array and check what value I see. If the value is zero I do nothing, but if it is one, I draw at certain position.
Maybe there is easier way to do this, and you can point me in that direction if there is no way to fix my problem.

EDIT:
Working solution was to change the enumeration to usual loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        int temp = [[fieldArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                {
                    CCSprite *x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"x.png"];
                    x.position = ccp(53, 265);
                    [self addChild:x z:1];
                    break;
                }

                case 1:
                {
                    CCSprite *x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"x.png"];
                    x.position = ccp(159, 265);
                    [self addChild:x z:1];
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd avoid the enumeration for this one and look at array positions first, then content.  (This isn't checked in the compiler but should give you the idea.  I assume it would be possible to write the `positionOfSpriteForIndex:` method to return the correct `ccp()` value.)

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < [fieldArray count]; idx++) {
    NSNumber *number = [fieldArray objectAtIndex:idx];
    CCSprite *x = nil;
    switch ([number intValue]) {
        case 1:
            x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"x.png"];
            x.position = [self positionOfSpriteForIndex:idx];
            [self addChild:x];
            break;

        case 2:
            x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"o.png"];
            x.position = [self positionOfSpriteForIndex:idx];
            [self addChild:x];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to usual for loop helped indeed, but I kept my code mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to put your `break` inside your brackets.

```
switch ([fieldArray indexOfObject:number]) {
                case 0:
                {
                    CCSprite *x = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"x.png"];
                    x.position = ccp(53,265);
                    [self addChild:x];
                break;
                }
```

Comment: Still same, break position was wrong, but positions still evaluated same.